# Retrieve insert id in stored procedure with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have stored procedure for insert booking record with details like `booking_id`, `name`, `r_id`, `t_id` etc. Now I want to know how to retrieve insert id of this record.

Stored procedure allow `LAST_INSERT_ID` only.
Here `MYSQL_INSERT_ID()` not working.
But here at a time two users perform booking then last record is different.

Please help me how to get insert record id for the booking through Stored Procedures in my sql  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the `last_insert_id()` value in different ways.

1. Define an `'OUT'` parameter in procedure signature, with proper data type.
2. Now, after executing `INSERT INTO...`, execute `set out_param := last_inser_id();`
3. Now you can read value of `'OUT'` parameter from the calling program or sql code body.

**Example 1**:

```
delimiter //

create procedure sp_so_q24075108( IN param1 int, ..., OUT param_auto_id int )
begin
  insert
     into table_name( col2, col3, ... )
   values ( param1, param2, ... );

  set param_auto_id := last_insert_id();
end;
//
delimiter ;


call sp_so_q24075108( 6, ..., @last_generated_id );
select @last_generated_id;
```

OR

1. Capture `'LAST_INSERT_ID()'` into user variable after executing `'INSERT'` statement.
2. Now you can read value of `'OUT'` parameter from the calling program or sql code body.

**Example 2**:

```
delimiter //

create procedure sp_so_q24075108( IN param1 int, ... )
begin
  insert
     into table_name( col2, col3, ... )
   values ( param1, param2, ... );

  set @auto_id := last_insert_id();
end;
//
delimiter ;

call sp_so_q24075108( 6, ... );
select @auto_id;
```

**Reference**:

[**CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)